# Visual Studio intellisense to show custom options for my properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I have no idea what the correct Google words are for this, so I'm sorry for the stupid question.

When I use intellisense in VS when coding, if I type something like "WindowStartupLocation = " I get a list of options to choose; "WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen" for example. I can choose this option rather than typing it manually.

I have a class with my properties in, one of the properties must have one of a set number of options in, so I figure I'd like to have the various options presented to me in VS.

How do I set my property as such?

Many thanks

```
internal class DatabaseLocks
    {
        public string Table { get; set; }
        public int Record { get; set; }
        public int User { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the enum information, but how do I apply this to my "Table" property rather than just the class?

Comment: using the enum def you provided in your answer you can declare a public property. no need to create a private backing variable. Just use: `public AfTables Table { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is an enum.

For example

```
public enum MyColors
{
     Red,
     Blue,
     Green,
     White,
     Blue
 }
```

When you use this enum, you'll get the drop down in intellisense like you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
enum MyKinds 
{
   Normal,
   Good,
   Bad,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `enum` type which will provide intellisense. You can get additional intellisense context by placing xml comments (`///<summary>`) on the type and individual members.

For example if you wanted to represent a set of Status, you could create an enum like this. The summary would appear as part of the intellisense information.
[image]

```
/// <summary>Indicates processing status</summary>
public enum ItemStatus
{
    /// <summary>Indicates item was not processed</summary>
    NotProcessed = 0,

    /// <summary>Item was rejected</summary>
    Rejected

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
private int myVar;

    public AfTables Table
    {
        get { return (AfTables)myVar; }
        set { myVar = (int) value; }
    }

    public enum AfTables
    {
        Users,
        PermissionGroups
    }
```

Comment: you should set `myVar` to type `AfTables`. Then you wouldn't have to cast in your `Table` property. Use `private AfTables myVar;`

Comment: Why use an integer for the backing feild? You can use an enum for the backing too.